# LowPriorityWrapAsScala no found after upgrading 2.9 Scala codebase to 2.11

Tags: scala, apache-camel

I get following runtime error:

```
12:57:16.627 WARN  AnnotationTypeConverterLoader - Ignoring converter type: org.apache.camel.scala.converter.ScalaMutableCollections as a dependent class could not be found: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/collection/convert/LowPriorityWrapAsScala
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/collection/convert/LowPriorityWrapAsScala
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.converter.AnnotationTypeConverterLoader.loadConverterMethods(AnnotationTypeConverterLoader.java:260) [camel-core-2.11.4.jar:2.11.4]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.converter.AnnotationTypeConverterLoader.load(AnnotationTypeConverterLoader.java:128) [camel-core-2.11.4.jar:2.11.4]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.converter.BaseTypeConverterRegistry.loadTypeConverters(BaseTypeConverterRegistry.java:518) [camel-core-2.11.4.jar:2.11.4]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.converter.DefaultTypeConverter.doStart(DefaultTypeConverter.java:47) [camel-core-2.11.4.jar:2.11.4]
    at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:61) [camel-core-2.11.4.jar:2.11.4]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.startService(DefaultCamelContext.java:1824) [camel-core-2.11.4.jar:2.11.4]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doAddService(DefaultCamelContext.java:965) [camel-core-2.11.4.jar:2.11.4]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.addService(DefaultCamelContext.java:926) [camel-core-2.11.4.jar:2.11.4]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.getTypeConverter(DefaultCamelContext.java:1114) [camel-core-2.11.4.jar:2.11.4]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.getTypeConverterRegistry(DefaultCamelContext.java:1131) [camel-core-2.11.4.jar:2.11.4]
...
```

Does this have something to do with Camel or am I missing some implicit somewhere?

Comment: Make sure you use 2.11 dependencies with a 2.11 compiler.

Comment: What version of camel-scala are you using? You can try the latest Camel 2.18.0 release which should be compiled with Scala 2.11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LowPriorityWrapAsScala is deprecated and no longer include in Scala 2.11.

Comment: If its deprecated is it not included? Or was it deprecated in earlier releases and then removed in 2.11. The error is about the class is no longer there.

Comment: True, it was deprecated earlier and not included anymore. I updated answer.